# REST routing best practices for adding a follower or like to a user

Tags: rest

Say I have a user and they can follow other users, and given that I'm passing a token with the logged in users credentials, which is the better best practice for a route for a "user to follow another user"?

POST /User/{userId}/follow

POST DATA: userIdToFollow

*(where I check that userId == authToken.userID)*

vs

PUT /User/{userId}/follow/{personToFollowUserId}

vs

POST /User/follow

POST DATA: userIdToFollow

*(where I just infer the userId from the auth token)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're striving for a RESTful system, you should be thinking of endpoints as being built from nouns, not verbs. I would suggest either

```
POST /users/27/followers
{ "userId": 45 }
```

or

```
POST /followers
{ "followerUserId": 45, "followeeUserId": 27 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would POST:

`POST /user/following/UserIdToFollow`

The UserId of the signed in user can be taken from the auth token and so including the signed in UserId is redundant.

PUT is used for updating a record and so unless you are specifically storing the fact that a user is NOT following another user POST would be more correct.

That way you POST to create a follow and then to unfollow you can DELETE to the same URL.